# How to convert <pre> block to a list block in WordPress gutenberg editor?

Tags: block-editor

When I copy a text block from another website to WordPress  gutenberg editor, it forms a `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` block. This block consists of several lines. I want to convert this block to a list block, and every line is a `<li>` element.

Currently, when I click the block option, there is only one option there that converts the block to a paragraph. However, when the `<pre>` block is converted to a paragraph, the line-breaks in the original block are missing. I have to add those line-breaks manually to form multiple paragraphs, then convert those paragraphs to a list block. Is there a convenient way to convert a `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` block to a list block directly?

Comment: Hello! This stack is for programmers, but it sounds like you want user support for the block editor, have you considered posting on the .org support forums instead? Any answer you get here will require basic programming knowledge to understand

Comment: @TomJNowell, by saying .org support forum, do you mean https://wordpress.org/support/forums/? Is there any domain/subdomain like xxx.stackexchange.com that I can post wordpress usage problems on?

Comment: yes that's the site, and not that I know of, maybe webmasters but I'm not super familiar with their scope. Stack Exchange has a lot of sites but not everything has a stack to fit the question. StackOverflow tries to be the catch all but that's specific to programming